Clarification on Independent Probabilities and Interference in Distant Photon Emitter Exercise
I am self-studying quantum information science and recently completed an exercise on distant photon emitter-- shown below and linked here. I would appreciate if anyone could help in clarifying my understanding of the first part.
Specifically, I would like to confirm if my interpretation is correct: Is the probability of both detectors clicking simply the product of the independent probabilities for each detector? Or do I need to consider an interference term, given that the photons are identical, even though they do not interact directly? My reasoning is that the detectors act as independent systems. Any input on whether this assumption is valid or if interference plays a role here would be very helpful. My solution is shown below along with the original problem for reference.
Thanks!
Original Question

My Solution
Part A
Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ denote the click outcome of detectors 1 and 2 respectively. That is, $H_i$ means detector $i$ registered a click. Click events are independent of one another, that is, detector 1 outputting $H_1$ occurs independently of detector 2 outputting $H_2$. Hence, the probability that both click simultaneously is:
$$pr(H_1 \cap H_2)=pr(H_1)pr(H_2)$$
$$pr(H_1)=|z_1|^2 = |z_{1a} + z_{1b}|^2$$
$$pr(H_2)=|z_1|^2 = |z_{2a} + z_{2b}|^2$$
where $z_{1a}$ and $z_{1b}$ denote the probability amplitudes corresponding to photon A and photon B traveling to detecter 1. The same is true for $z_{2a}$ and $z_{2b}$ but for detector 2:
Now we compute both probabilities, and then compute the joint probability.
Detector 1
$$pr(H_1)=|z_1|^2 = |z + ze^{i\phi}|^2$$
$$=(z + ze^{i\phi})(z^\dagger + z^\dagger e^{-i\phi})$$
$$=zz^\dagger + zz^\dagger e^{-i\phi} + zz^\dagger e^{i\phi}+zz^\dagger e^{i\phi}e^{-i\phi}$$
$$=p + p e^{-i\phi} + p e^{i\phi} +p$$
$$=2p + p e^{-i\phi} + p e^{i\phi}$$
$$=p(2 + e^{-i\phi} + e^{i\phi})$$
$$=p(2 + 2\cos\phi)$$
$$=2p(1 + 1\cos\phi)$$
Detector 2
$$pr(H_2)=|z_2|^2 = |z + ze^{i\phi}|^2$$
$$=(z + ze^{i\phi})(z^\dagger + z^\dagger e^{-i\phi})$$
$$=zz^\dagger + zz^\dagger e^{-i\phi} + zz^\dagger e^{i\phi}+zz^\dagger e^{i\phi}e^{-i\phi}$$
$$=p + p e^{-i\phi} + p e^{i\phi} +p$$
$$=2p + p e^{-i\phi} + p e^{i\phi}$$
$$=p(2 + e^{-i\phi} + e^{i\phi})$$
$$=p(2 + 2\cos\phi)$$
$$=2p(1 + 1\cos\phi)$$
Final joint probability
$$pr(H_1 \cap H_2)=2p(1 + 1\cos\phi)2p(1 + 1\cos\phi)$$
$$=4p^2(1 + 1\cos\phi)(1 + 1\cos\phi)$$
$$=4p^2(1 + 1\cos\phi)(1 + 1\cos\phi)$$
$$=4p^2(1 +\cos\phi)^2, \text{where } p=|z|^2$$
Part B
Assuming $z\approx\frac{1}{r} e^{\frac{i2\pi}{\lambda}}$ where r is the distance between the detectors and the starts and $\lambda$ is a fixed constant, we can determine r by first running a number of experiments to approximate the probability $Pr(H_1\cap H_2)$ say as $x$. That is $x \approx Pr(H_1\cap H_2)$
We can then solve for $r$:
$$x = 4p^2(1 +\cos\phi)^2$$
$$x = 4p^2(1 +\cos\phi)^2$$
$$\frac{x}{4(1+cos\phi)^2} = p^2$$
$$p^2=\frac{x}{4(1+cos\phi)^2}$$
$$p=\sqrt{\frac{x}{4(1+cos\phi)^2}}$$
$$p=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2(1+cos\phi)}$$
Since $p = |z|^2$
$$|\frac{1}{r} e^{\frac{i2\pi}{\lambda}}|^2=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2(1 + cos\phi)}$$
$$\frac{1}{r} e^{\frac{i2\pi}{\lambda}}\frac{1}{r} e^{\frac{-i2\pi}{\lambda}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2(1 + cos\phi)}$$
$$\frac{1}{r^2}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2(1 + cos\phi)}$$
$$r^2=\frac{2(1 + cos\phi)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$r^2=\frac{2(1 + cos\phi)}{\sqrt{x}}$$

You didn’t explicitly mention it, but this is an example of the Hanbury Brown and Twiss effect. This was originally discovered in the 1950’s by a pair of astronomers. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbury_Brown_and_Twiss_effect

I would say there is a lot of confusion about these quantum phenomenon and interpretations in the science literature. Fundamentally photons only interfere within apparati such as DSE and spectrometers. The high school version has photons cancelling each other which is not true. Hanberry and Twiss experiment and Glaubers explanation (Nobel prize) are difficult to research, explanations are not clear.  Note that in Hansberry Twiss the sources A and B are in the same star/source .... which is different than the question above.

Your source is an independent effort by 4 physicists with a strong interest in quantum encryption ... I really don't like their DSE interpretation at all.

@PhysicsDave This question specifies that the photons are indistinguishable (identical). So the essential physics is the same as HBT. The (anti-)/bunching effect of HBT is an example of (destructive)/constructive interference between 2 photons.
